# basic search bar using VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, search, searchbar

I actually don't know how to make a search bar. Can someone give me instructions of creating one? And how will it be displayed if i generate the search bar.

I would like to use a textbox and a button for this search bar. It's like, when you input a data on the textbox and click the button, it will go in a new form wherein the result from the inputted keyword will be displayed. The data is coming from the database I have. The database consist of list of students, and the keywords you need to type on the search bar is their student_ID or their names.

Thank you to those who will respond!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Describe your problem in details. like where u use , why u use, how you want to use the search-bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you want is a database of past websites that get suggested from the textbox..... If so just click on the textbox and turn the auto-completion mode to suggest and auto complete source to allurl.

If you want the button to go to the website that is in the textbox then the code for the button is (name of webbrowser).navigate(name of textbox).text

If this is not what you want just tell me what it is I have some experience with web browsing in vb.net

Comment: (I hope I could explain it clearly. Hahaha~) Anyway, i was thinking of searching into the database only. My system is Monitoring System and I wish to create a search bar which searches the database I have then return the result. I hope you could help me with this. I badly need to finish our system in 2 days.

Comment: Simple to do just add your textbox (no button needed) make sure the auto complete mode is suggest and auto complete source is your database. This will give website suggestions when searching from your database. Is this good enough? I suggest trying it and seeing if it is good enough as it takes only few mins to do. Is it a database of websites? Otherwise this won't work.

Comment: Thank you for responding, @Md5 Software. Uhm No, it's not database of websites. But more on database of list of students. But I'll try it, anyway. :)